# Rotate Cube to 'look at' mouse from Python in OpenGL

Tags: python, opengl, python-2.7

I am working on making a proof of concept bubble popper game, so I need the cannon to follow the mouse. I am currently trying to have a cube rotate around the z axis to follow the mouse. I am using the code below and it produces the results below that. The cannon sits in the middle of the bottom of a `550 x 550` window. The results printed below the code are when the mouse is at the lower right corner, the center of the window, and the lower left. So I would anticipate the resulting angles to be `-90, ~0, 90` But well, not so much. This may turn out to be a programming issue or it may turn out to be a math issue. I am pretty sure the math works because I tested it outside of the mouse position and it gave me the proper results. Can you see the problem?

I have also tried normalizing the vectors first and swapping which points were put in first, it didn't do anything.

I have also included the code I use to set up the window and drawing space.

```
    def cannon_rotation(self):
        vector1 = self.points_to_vector((self.width/2, 20), (self.width/2, 30))
        vector2 = self.points_to_vector((self.width/2, 20), self.mouse_location)
        print 'vector1', vector1
        print 'vector2', vector2
        a = self.angle(vector1, vector2)
        print a
        return a

    def points_to_vector(self, point1, point2):
        return point2[0] - point1[0], point2[1] - point1[1]

    def dot_product(self, vector1, vector2):
        return vector1[0] * vector2[0] + vector1[1] * vector2[1]

    def length(self, vector):
        return (self.dot_product(vector, vector)) ** .5

    def angle(self, vector1, vector2):
        dot_a_b = self.dot_product(vector1, vector2)
        len_a_b = (self.length(vector1)) * (self.length(vector2))
        angle = dot_a_b / len_a_b
        print 'dot_a_b', dot_a_b
        print 'len_a_b', len_a_b
        print 'angle', angle
        angle_in_degrees = acos(angle) * 180 / pi
        print angle_in_degrees
        return angle_in_degrees


    ###Create Window
    def reshape(self, height, width):
        if height >= 90 and width >= 90:
            self.index_location_dict = self.create_index_location_dict(height, width)
            self.height = height
            self.width = width
            glViewport(0, 0, height, width)
            glMatrixMode(GL_PROJECTION)
            glLoadIdentity()
            glOrtho(0.0, height, width, 0.0, -20.0, 20.0)
            glEnable(GL_DEPTH_TEST)
        else:
            self.game_over = True
```

The results:

```
Mouse Position (535, 536)
vector1 (0, 10) 
vector2 (260, 516) 
dot_a_b 5160 
len_a_b 5778.02734504 
result 0.893038348881
angle 26.7424369246

Mouse Position (276, 386) 
vector1 (0, 10) 
vector2 (1, 366) 
dot_a_b 3660 
len_a_b 3660.01366118 
result 0.999996267452
angle 0.15654545612

Mouse Position(9, 535) 
vector1 (0, 10) 
vector2 (-266, 515) 
dot_a_b 5150 len_a_b
5796.38680559 
result 0.888484528851
angle 27.316573085
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`(self.width/2, 20)` specifies the center of the top edge. You need to swap it to `(self.width/2, height - 20)`.

You don't need to calculate `vector1` this way. It can always be set to `(0, 1)` (pointing downwards).

Furthermore, check your projection matrix:

```
glOrtho(0.0, height, width, 0.0, -20.0, 20.0)
```

Either you have a different OpenGL than me or you have mixed up the parameters:

```
void glOrtho( GLdouble   left,  
              GLdouble   right,  
              GLdouble   bottom,  
              GLdouble   top,  
              GLdouble   nearVal,  
              GLdouble   farVal);
```